# php_posix on mac osx

Tags: php, macos, posix

I'm trying to enable php_posix functions support for php 5.3.6 on Mac OsX 10.6.

Although php doc says posix functions are enabled by default,
( http://php.net/manual/en/posix.installation.php )

if I run a php script with the posix_isatty() function, I get an error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function posix_isatty()

??

My safe_mode is set to Off as recommended by php documentation.
I used macport to install php, and it seems that they didn't use  --disable-posix.

Here is the portion of my phpinfo() that proves it:

> Configure Command     './configure' '--prefix=/opt/local' '--mandir=/opt/local/share/man' '--infodir=/opt/local/share/info' '--with-config-file-path=/opt/local/etc/php5' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/local/var/db/php5' '--disable-all' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-ctype' '--enable-dom' '--enable-fileinfo' '--enable-filter' '--enable-hash' '--enable-json' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-pdo' '--enable-phar' '--enable-session' '--enable-simplexml' '--enable-tokenizer' '--enable-xml' '--enable-xmlreader' '--enable-xmlwriter' '--with-bz2=/opt/local' '--with-mhash=/opt/local' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/local' '--with-readline=/opt/local' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/local' '--with-zlib=/opt/local' '--without-pear' '--disable-cgi' '--with-apxs2=/opt/local/apache2/bin/apxs'

if I run `php -m`, php_posix doesn't appear in the modules list.

So my conclusion at this point is: it's not installed.

How can I install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you are using the switch "--disable-all", which -- as far as i know -- deactivates *all* extensions including posix. I would recommend building PHP without "--disable-all" and use the extension-specific "--disable..." switch if you really need to deactivate some extension.

Answer (score 5):

Mac Ports has a package for the PHP Posix module:

```
sudo port install php55-posix
```

Replace 55 with the version of php you installed.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The OP used macports to install PHP, so re-building it is an entirely different path. Using this command will take 10 seconds!